# useState Object not updating properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

When we try to update useState object properties simultaneously. its not updating.

```
const [stateData, setStatedata] = useState({
id: 0,
name: '',
address: '',
street: '',
city: '',
country: '',
property1: '',
property2: ''
etc...
});
```

When I try to update property1 on a text change event

```
const test = () => {
if(case == 1){
setStatedata({
 ...stateData,
 property1: '123'
});
}
else{
// Do something
}
setStatedata({
 ...stateData,
 property2: '654'
});
}
```

In this case property1 value will not be set to 123.

But its not waiting for property1 value to be updated. The previously updated value isn't always there.

If I need 20 or more state properties, which is better solution?

1. Object
2. A single state for each property

Comment: can you please add more code snippets? how you are updating property1 and property2? which function are you calling to update both properties? are you updating both properties in same function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update the state value in the following way:

```
setStatedata(state=> ({
   ...state,
   property2: '65554'
}));
```

In addition, you can use a custom hook from my lib that implements a deep state manager ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-deep-state-forked-32qmu?file=/src/TestComponent.js)):

```
import React from "react";
import { useAsyncDeepState } from "use-async-effect2";

function TestComponent(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useAsyncDeepState({
    x: 123,
    y: 456
  });

  const incX = () => {
    setState(({ x }) => ({ x: x + 1 }));
  };

  const incY = () => {
    setState(({ y }) => ({ y: y + 1 }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="component">
      <div className="caption">useAsyncDeepState demo</div>
      <div>state.x : {state.x}</div>
      <div>state.y : {state.y}</div>
      <button onClick={() => incX()}>Inc X</button>
      <button onClick={() => incY()}>Inc Y</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If using in the context of async code and you need to wait for updates [Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-deep-state-5c9d0?file=/src/TestComponent.js)

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { useAsyncDeepState } from "use-async-effect2";

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

function TestComponent(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useAsyncDeepState({
    counter: 0,
    computedCounter: 0
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(({ counter }) => ({
      computedCounter: counter * 2
    }));
  }, [state.counter]);

  const inc = useCallback(() => {
    (async () => {
      await delay(1000);
      await setState(({ counter }) => ({ counter: counter + 1 }));
      console.log("computedCounter=", state.computedCounter);
    })();
  });

  return (<button onClick={inc}>Inc</button>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i try this code work for me you can try this:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-sea-3bur6?file=/src/App.js:87-690)

```
 const [stateData, setStatedata] = useState({
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    address: '',
    street: '',
    city: '',
    country: '',
    property1: '',
    property2: ''
    });
    
   const test = () => {
    setStatedata({
      ...stateData,
      property1: '123'
     });
  
   }
   const test2 = () => {
   
     setStatedata({
      ...stateData,
      property2: '65554'
     });
   }
   console.log(stateData)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={() => test()}>Click Here</h1>
      <hr />
      <h1 onClick={() => test2()}>Click Here2</h1>
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: In some scenario i need to update state using if else condition
```
const test = () => {
if(case == 1){
    setStatedata({
      ...stateData,
      property1: "123"
    });
}
else{
//Something
}
    setStatedata({
      ...stateData,
      property2: "65554"
    });
  };
```
If case ==1 then both update will work. so first updated value will not be there for property1

Answer (score 0):

You should pass two parameter text change event click.

1. Object property name that you want to change in state object. ex:- property1
2. Value that you want to set for that Object property.ex:- Any value(text event value)

And your test function like this

```
const test = (key,value) => {
    setStatedata({...stateData,[key]:value})
}
```

Now you don't need to create multiple functions to change object values.